# React native Reference child failed

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, react-native

```js
const { width: WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window');
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
today = mm + dd + yyyy;

class Attendance extends Component {
    state = {
        image: null,
        submit: false,
        loading: false,
        face: null,
        confidence: 0,
        class: '',
        flag: ''
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
        firebase
         .database()
         .ref('users/')
         .child(currentUser.uid)
         .on('value', snap => 
            this.setState({ 
                face: snap.val().image,
                class: snap.val().stream_sem
            })
         );
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.Conatiner}>
                <Loader loading={this.state.loading} />
                {this.renderContent()}
            </View>
        );
    }
    renderContent = () =>  {
        firebase.database().ref('attendance')
        .child(this.state.class)
        .child(today)
        .on("value", snap => {
            this.setState({ flag: snap.val().flag});
        });
        if(this.state.flag === "0") {
            //**something**
        }
        else {
            //**something**
        }
    }
}
```

When i am trying to write `this.state.class`, it is showing reference child failed. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6BZ9.jpg)  is the error detail i am getting.
My firebase database [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiFoA.png) is here. Can you please tell where i am going wrong. I want to access "flag" part of the database. `CSE8` should match with the users `stream_sem`
ThankYou in advance

Comment: Can you add a console.log before `snap.val().stream_sem`? to check what value you are getting?
Also one more `console.log(this.state.class)` in `renderContent` method.

Answer (score 1):

When your renderContent is called first time, your state.class is empty string, remember that firebase snapshot will be loaded asynchronously. Also, do not attach listeners to firebase in a render function that is called by render method, you will end up having a lot of listeners.

Your logic should be something like:

1. Get user data from firebase
2. If data is not null, set state
3. After [state is set](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296?gi=bc840ec3bb34), get attendance data from database
4. Set state appropriately

Always write rough algorithm before jumping state to dev (Ignore if you already knew that). Happy learning, Cheers!

Comment: Yes i understood what you said. And its working. But how to hold the rendeContent() function till my this.state.flag is not affected by setState. For now i have to reload the page to get the correct output. At first time it directly goes inside the ELSE condition.

Comment: As mentioned in the link also, setState function accepts a callback as second argument, please accept the answer if your original query is solved, Thanks